# Long power button press delete

Tags: hardware, shutdown

Is it possible to disable the shutdown on long press of the hardware power button? I already disabled any actions on single, short press, but the computer still turns off on a long press of the power button. How can I remove that?

Comment: Check you BIOS, some have the option in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a hardware related matter, and can't be controlled by any OS. You could find something helpful in your BIOS, nothing much more.